# Is there a way to store a Windows Service name in a property value when the service fails unexpectedly?

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I have a batch script that runs a Powershell script when a Windows Service stops unexpectedly. This Powershell script is run via Recovery Options on the service and sends an email alerting admins that the service failed and they need to go check on it.

Given that these scripts will be used on a number of servers and services, I'd like to find a way to grab the name of the service that failed and store it as a property value instead of hard-coding service names and creating copies of this email script for every service it will be used on.

Is there a way to store the name of a service that triggered the script on failure and pass it to Powershell?

**Edit:** When a service fails, I've taken the advice of **thepip3r** and have it just running the powershell script on failure, forgoing any need for a batch script. 
[Here is the recovery option setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tfh3S.png)

Testing this works and does send the email, but how would I call the "TestService" name that I've given it within the script?

For reference, here is the code in my ps1 script:

```
$From = "testing@test.com"
$To = "me@test.com"
$Subject =  "[SERVICE NAME VALUE] Failed to Restart"                           
$Body = "Please go to " + $env:computername +" and restart it"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.server"
$SMTPPort = 587
$userName = 'user123'
$securePwd = Get-Content 'filepathtoencryptedpass\Secure.txt' | ConvertTo-SecureString
$cred = New-Object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $userName, $securePwd

Send-MailMessage -From $From -To $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort -Priority High -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Your opening sentence is clear, "I have a batch script that runs a Powershell script when a Windows Service stops unexpectedly." You therefore already know the name of the Windows service which is stopping unexpectedly, and therefore have no need whatsoever to not hard code its name. Now if for instance your script was to report every single service ending, that would be slightly different, but then again, your admins would be run off their feet. Regardless of that, this site helps to fix a issue with your code, so in order to do that you must provide us with the content of both your scripts.

Comment: instead of calling a batch, you could call PowerShell directly (powershell.exe) and target a PS1 file you've created.  you can side step hard-coding the service name in the script and multiple scripts by having your PS1 parameterized.  Then on the Run on First Failure config, your commandline is something like powershell.exe -File myservicemontior.ps1 'servicename1'.  In this way, it's only one script file but when you set it up on the service, has a different name setting based on the recovery configuration.